How to host pytorch on heroku or aws without exceedig size limit
I have a django app that utilizes RoBERTa (pytorch for sentiment analysis on tweets). I can't figure out any solution for hosting the app anywhere. All of the apps have a 500mb slug max limit and torch is larger than that alone. I don't know how to proceed so if anyone has experience with this or if you know of an api that I can hit for sentiment anaylsis that would be much appreciated. I've tried for several weeks to no avail.

related: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-slimmed-down-pytorch-for-computation/78771/5
you might get better luck with frameworks specific to evaluation, but in that thread, it says that Cuda + cudnn itself is more than 2 GiO, so it is going to be hard to fit anything that uses cuda in less than that
